# Firebase problems deploying functions

Tags: javascript, flutter, paypal

Am trying to deploy a cloud function to firebase related to paypal payments. However I keep getting an error that I dont understand. Here is my function index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//   functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
//   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });
const braintree = require("braintree");

const gateway= new braintree.BraintreeGateway({
  environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
  merchantId: "g4rwjwrjjwjewjjewj",
  publicKey: "wkklljwljhtwkthkth",
  privateKey: "ktktjhjhttrhjerhjterh",
});

exports.paypalPayment= functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) =>{
  const nonceFromTheClient = req.body.payment_method_nonce;
  const deviceData = req.body.device_data;
  // const amount = req.body.amount;

  gateway.transaction.sale({
    amount: '10.00',
    // paymentMethodNonce: nonceFromTheClient,
    paymentMethodNonce: 'fake-paypal-one-time-nonce',
    deviceData: deviceData,
    options: {
      submitForSettlement: true
    }
  }, (err, result) => {
    if (err != null) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.json({result: "success"});
    }
  }

  );
});
```

Below is the terminal message when trying to deploy

```
i  deploying functions
+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (45.96 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 12 function paypalPayment(us-central1)...

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        paypalPayment(us-central1)

To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only "functions:paypalPayment"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

If it's any help, am trying to intergrate paypal payment with flutter

Comment: Did you try downgrading? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66140151/deployment-error-deploying-cloud-function-with-firebase-trigger/66140792#66140792 There is an open issue on GitHub

Comment: Unfortunately downgrading did not work